# In Flutter, how can I define a baseline for a Stateless widget?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout, baseline

I have created a stateless widget, and I want to define a **baseline** for it, so that I can use it with the Baseline widget (https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Baseline-class.html).

How can I do that?

Comment: Isn't `Baseline` widget actually doing that for you ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to define a baseline you can't do it directly in the stateless widget. You need to mess around its corresponding `RenderBox` that needs to implement the `computeDistanceToActualBaseline()` method.

Give a look to the `ListTile` implementation [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/af5d4c688205c7b348201c702b05c03f1f5eb9ff/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L876). You will see that the `_RenderListTile` RenderBox implements the above method returning the baseline of the title widget.

```
  @override
  double computeDistanceToActualBaseline(TextBaseline baseline) {
    assert(title != null);
    final BoxParentData parentData = title.parentData;
    return parentData.offset.dy + title.getDistanceToActualBaseline(baseline);
  }
```

In this case, the baseline of the title is the bottom of the Text widget.

All this is needed because the `Baseline` widget tries to get the baseline of the child widget. If you don't provide a explicit baseline with the above method, it just uses its bottom position.

You can find below an example of a `BaselineBox` where you can set an arbitrary baseline from top.

```
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class BaselineBox extends SingleChildRenderObjectWidget {
  const BaselineBox({Key key, @required this.baseline, Widget child})
      : assert(baseline != null),
        super(key: key, child: child);

  final double baseline;

  @override
  RenderBaselineBox createRenderObject(BuildContext context) =>
      new RenderBaselineBox(baseline: baseline);

  @override
  void updateRenderObject(
      BuildContext context, RenderBaselineBox renderObject) {
    renderObject.baseline = baseline;
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(new DoubleProperty('baseline', baseline));
  }
}

class RenderBaselineBox extends RenderProxyBox {
  RenderBaselineBox({
    RenderBox child,
    @required double baseline,
  })  : assert(baseline != null),
        assert(baseline >= 0.0),
        assert(baseline.isFinite),
        _baseline = baseline,
        super(child);

  double get baseline => _baseline;
  double _baseline;

  set baseline(double value) {
    assert(value != null);
    assert(value >= 0.0);
    assert(value.isFinite);
    if (_baseline == value) return;
    _baseline = value;
    markNeedsLayout();
  }

  @override
  double computeDistanceToActualBaseline(TextBaseline baselineType) {
    return _baseline;
  }

  @override
  void debugFillProperties(DiagnosticPropertiesBuilder properties) {
    super.debugFillProperties(properties);
    properties.add(new DoubleProperty('baseline', baseline));
  }
}
```

Comment: I see that `ListTile` returns a `InkWell` containing a `_ListTile`, which is a `RenderObjectWidget`, which creates a  `_ListTileElement` and a `_RenderListTile`. And the `_RenderListTile` extends `RenderBox`.

Does that mean MyWidget should be a `RenderObjectWidget`, which creates a  `_MyWidgetElement` and a `_RenderMyWidget` that extends `RenderBox`?

It there an easier way?

Comment: Ideally, I could have a `AddBaseline` widget that I could use like this: `widget = AddBaseline(baseline:15.0, child: wiget);`

Comment: I have edited the answer and added an implementation of a `BaselineBox`.

Comment: Wow, great. But I'm getting this weird error: `The following assertion was thrown during performLayout():`
`Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null`
`(package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1636:50)`
Which is here:
`_cachedBaselines.putIfAbsent(baseline, () => computeDistanceToActualBaseline(baseline));` (in box.dart)

Comment: @MarcG initialize this `final bool fromBottom;`

Comment: I will have a look when a I get home. For the moment I have replaced 100 with `child.size.height` inside `computeDistanceToActualBaseline()`. I had forgotten it after doing some tests.

Comment: Finally this should work. I have removed the `fromBottom` flag because it requires dealing with the child height and that can't be simply done by overriding the `computeDistanceToActualBaseline()` method.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Nice work @chemamolins, I haven't tried it yet. But looks fine to me, what about negative baseline, that should be possible. Is there a particular reason you limit it to >= 0.0?

Comment: No special reason. Just submitted it here as an example. I'm sure it could be enhanced with more options as well.